# PostGIS table structure question

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, php

I have been using QGIS to insert point data accompanied by information for each point into PostGIS. When I open PGAdmin to take a look at the table rows I noticed a column near the start of each row called "geom" which is obviously point geometry with I believe a SRID of 4326.

Now my main questions are:

1. Does QGIS add this to the database or is this something that PostGIS adds automatically.
2. I'm going to be using a form which calls upon PHP to insert values into this databse table. Do I need to figure out the geometry or will PostGIS handle this for me?

I have looked at alot of information about SRID but a good bit of it is over my head.

Answer (score 2):

I depends on how you create or add the table to the database. If you upload your table to the database through any tools like shp2pgsql or QGIS a geometry column is made for your to store the spatial data in.

You will need to manually create the geometry when inserting to the database.

```
INSERT INTO mytable(mycol1, mycol2, geom)
VALUES(1, 2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(11.1 55.3)', 4326));
```

If you have long lat columns that you insert to, you can create the geometry after your long lat insert like:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326);
```